# Are singular values independent of the scalar product?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

Let $H$ be a hilbert space $ (\varphi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq H$ a Rieszbasis and by $\tilde{\varphi_j}$ we denote the biorthogonal sequence. Meaning

$ \langle \varphi_j , \tilde{\varphi_k} \rangle = \delta_{j,k} $

Let $\tau_j > 0 $ be a sequence in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$. Define

$D: H \to H$

$D: f \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^\infty \tau_j \langle f , \tilde{\varphi_j} \rangle \varphi_j $

The Eigenvalues being $\lambda_j (D) = \tau_j$.

The Question is what are the singular values of D?

$s_j (D) = \sqrt{\lambda_j (D^* D) } $

What I got so far there exists an other equivalent scalar product on $H$ such that $D$ is self adjoint. Therefor $s_{j,2} (D) = \lambda_j (D)$. But this only helps if the definition of singular values is independent of the concrete scalar product.

Now the other ansatz is going via Approximation Numbers, there is the question under wich conditions does

$a_j (D) = \lambda_j (D)$

while $a_j (D) := \min \{ \vert \vert D - T \vert \vert \,\ \vert \,\ rank (T) = j-1 \} $, hold?

Comment: The answer is yes the singular values depend on the scalarproduct being used. 

If you take $H= \mathbb{R}^2$ for example and look at the Matrix $D_{1,1}=1, D_{1,2}=5, D_{2,1}=0, D_{2,2}=1$ the Eigenvalues are always 1 and the singular values depend on the concrete scalarproduct being used. One can obtain Inequalities such that the singular values behave similiar to the eigenvalues for Operators.